# Confusing MySql Join on 3 Tables

Tags: c#, mysql, join

Morning all,

I am trying to get a 3 table joint to work, using Ef.net (Not core) and Linq but for the life of me cant get a result I am expecting.

The Scenario:  We have a web page where people perform a lookup,  These users are not logged in but their IP addresses are recorded against the Lookup.

Databases:
Accounts (Contains AccountID, Company Name, EmailAddress)
Lookups (Contains iPAddress, searchResult, dateSearched)
iPAddresses (Contains AccountID, ipAddress)

The Requirement:  I have been trying to create a query where I pass it an AccountID, and it tells me how many Lookups the account has done based on the iPAddresses they have searched with.

Attempted Code:  The following is about as close as I thought I was to getting it working but still returns no results

```
public int getLookups(int accountID)
{
        var query = (from p in mySqlEntities.individual_lookups
                    join meta in mySqlEntities.ip_addresses on p.ipAddress equals meta.ip_address
                    where p.accountID == accountID
                    select p.id).Count();
        return query;
}
```

I'm not quite sure where I am going wrong here, but any help in the matter would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: You are joining 2 tables, not three...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading you're question correctly, then these are your tables

> Databases: Accounts (Contains AccountID, Company Name, EmailAddress) Lookups (Contains iPAddress, searchResult, dateSearched) iPAddresses (Contains AccountID, ipAddress)

Which means that `mySqlEntities.individual_lookups` doesn't have an `accountId` column, but your `mySqlEntities.ip_addresses` does.

Change your WHERE clause to the below and see if you get any further:

```
where meta.accountID == accountID
```

Comment: I cant believe it was that!  Thank you so much